# Displaying only not NULL data with user ioptions

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 tables `user_points` and `users`. In users i store users details like this

```
id | uid     | fname   | lname  | pic
1  | 5TQ4G1  | Zen     | D      | img1.png
2  | ZIF852  | Mike    | Lois   | img2.png
3  | FW20H6  | Vicky   | S      | vick.jpg
4  | PCD8Q5  | Rocky   | M      | rocks.jpg
```

And in user_points table i store the values for each option which user has selected

```
id | user_id   | opt1  | opt2  | opt3  | opt4 | opt5 | opt6 
1  | 5TQ4G1    | 20    | 30    | 60    |      |      |     
2  | ZIF852    | 20    |       | 50    | 10   |      |
3  | PCD8Q5    |       |  10   |       |      |      | 50
```

I want to display the result like this

```
Zen - Image - opt1.png, opt2.png, opt3.png 
Mike - Image - opt1.png, opt3.png, opt4.png
Rocky - Image - Opt2.png, opt6.png
```

There will be 6 options and each option i have stored image opt1.png, opt2.png...

My code is

```
<?php

$sql5 = "SELECT ud.id, ud.opt1, ud.opt2, ud.opt3, ud.opt4, ud.opt5, ud.opt6, u.uid, u.fname, u.pic FROM user_details ud LEFT JOIN users u ON ud.user_id=u.uid GROUP BY ud.user_id";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql5);

while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {

 echo "<div class='col-xs-9'>";
    if($row1["pic"]=='') { 
    $img =   "<img src='pics/profile.png' height='30px' alt='".$row1["fname"]."' title='".$row1["fname"]."' style='padding-right:5px;' />";
    }
    elseif($row1["pic"]!='') { 
    $img = "<img src='pics/".$row1["uid"]."/".$row1["pic"]."' height='30px' alt='".$row1["fname"]."' title='".$row1["fname"]."' style='padding-right:5px;'' />";
    }
                    if($row1['opt1']!=NULL)
            { 

    $options  .= "<img src='img/opt1.png' height='15px' /> ,  ";

    }
    if($row1['opt2']!=NULL)
    {

    $options  .= "<img src='img/opt2.png'  height='15px' /> ,  ";

    }
     if($row1['opt3']!=NULL)
    {
    $options  .= "<img src='img/opt3.png' height='15px' /> ,  ";

    }
    if($row1['opt4']!=NULL)
    {
    $options  .= "<img src='img/opt4.png' height='15px' /> , ";

    }
     if($row1['opt5']!=NULL)
    {
    $options  .= "<img src='img/opt5.png' height='15px' /> , ";

    }
    if($row1['opt6']!=NULL)
    {
    $options  .= "<img src='img/opt6.png' height='15px' />   ";

    }

    echo  $row1['fname']." - ".$img." - ".$options;
}
echo "</div>";
```

But i am getting result like this

`Zen - Image - opt1.png, opt2.png, opt3.png 
Mike - Image - opt1.png, opt2.png, opt3.png, opt1.png, opt3.png, opt4.png
Rocky - Image - opt1.png, opt2.png, opt3.png, opt1.png, opt3.png, opt4.png, opt2.png, opt6.png`

For `Zen` its correct. For `Mike` it displays his data along with `Zen's` data and for `Rocky` its display his data along with `zen, Rocky` data. Which loop i should correct i am not getting.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. Fix your schema.

Comment: Yup! I will definitely do that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are concatenating values into `$options` using the

```
$options .= .....
```

After your while, initialise the `$options` variable to clear out the last loops contents.

```
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    $options = '';
```

Comment: Yeah! Thank you very much RiggsFolly!

Comment: @B.Desai Before you start thinking it was me, it was not!

Comment: I know @RiggsFolly

Comment: Because our answers are almost same

Comment: Done @RiggsFolly

Comment: @B.Desai Ahh I see now. YCS is in the house. That explains it

Answer (score 1):

As your string is being added you need to empty `$options` value at last

```
<?php

$sql5 = "SELECT ud.id, ud.opt1, ud.opt2, ud.opt3, ud.opt4, ud.opt5, ud.opt6, u.uid, u.fname, u.pic FROM user_details ud LEFT JOIN users u ON ud.user_id=u.uid GROUP BY ud.user_id";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql5);

while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {

 echo "<div class='col-xs-9'>";
    if($row1["pic"]=='') { 
    $img =   "<img src='pics/profile.png' height='30px' alt='".$row1["fname"]."' title='".$row1["fname"]."' style='padding-right:5px;' />";
    }
    elseif($row1["pic"]!='') { 
    $img = "<img src='pics/".$row1["uid"]."/".$row1["pic"]."' height='30px' alt='".$row1["fname"]."' title='".$row1["fname"]."' style='padding-right:5px;'' />";
    }
                    if($row1['opt1']!=NULL)
            { 

    $options  .= "<img src='img/opt1.png' height='15px' /> ,  ";

    }
    if($row1['opt2']!=NULL)
    {

    $options  .= "<img src='img/opt2.png'  height='15px' /> ,  ";

    }
     if($row1['opt3']!=NULL)
    {
    $options  .= "<img src='img/opt3.png' height='15px' /> ,  ";

    }
    if($row1['opt4']!=NULL)
    {
    $options  .= "<img src='img/opt4.png' height='15px' /> , ";

    }
     if($row1['opt5']!=NULL)
    {
    $options  .= "<img src='img/opt5.png' height='15px' /> , ";

    }
    if($row1['opt6']!=NULL)
    {
    $options  .= "<img src='img/opt6.png' height='15px' />   ";

    }

    echo  $row1['fname']." - ".$img." - ".$options;
    $options = "";
}
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Hey Thanks a ton! i was missing this small thing. I can accept your answer only after 9 mins !! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer. Too long for a comment:

A normalised user_points table might look as follows:

```
user_id opt val
      1   1  20
      1   2  30
      1   3  60
      2   1  20
      2   3  50
      2   4  10
      3   2  10
      3   6  50
```

Comment: Strictly there is nothing wrong with OP's design, IF there is only ever going to be the possibility of 6 options.

Comment: this IS the answer

Comment: @YourCommonSense But not to the question that was asked

Comment: @RiggsFolly That is true. However, I think that depends a little on how we interpret 1NF - but I have to admit that it can become a boring digression.